# ObjectDisposedException with dbcontext

Tags: c#, exception, timer

I seems to struggle with this exception, I know what a DisposedObjectException means I just don't know where to troubleshoot.
Many question on stackoverflow where that suits my problem but doesn't seem to fix my issue.

my dbcontext is scoped as far as I know, I tried to set my service as well as scoped and transient.

it throws the exception inside when I want to add my host to the database.

Any ideas where to troubleshoot or where to look?
my service:

```
public class TaskManager
{
    private readonly IListService _listService;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private Timer networkTimer;

    public TaskManager(IListService listService, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {            
        _listService = listService;
        _context = context;
        networkTimer = new Timer(async (e) => await DoApiCalls(), null, 30000, 5000);            
    }


    public async Task DoApiCalls()
    {
        var hosts = _listService.GetActiveHosts();

        if (hosts != null)
        {
            foreach (var host in hosts)
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7224/api/network");
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NetworkAdapter>>(content);
                        host.Adapters = Mapper.Map(result);
                        _context.HostInformation.Add(host);
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        //failed to get network probably offline
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }                       
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET core application? Why TaskManager is scoped? Where is it injected?. It seems to me that task manager should be a hosted service. Object disposed exception is not the worse thing that can happen. Your code can cause undefined behavior because the context can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time

Comment: no blazor application in .net6, all are injected in de builder.services, currently the taskmanager is transient.

Comment: Sever side blazor? I'm asking where it is injected and used. I'm not asking where it is configured

Comment: As @JesúsLópez says, use a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services) for this type of thing, and then create and dispose a scoped `DbContext` each iteration (the linked article shows how).  DbContexts are supposed to be short-lived, not kept around like that. Also inject and use an `IHttpClientFactory` and use it to create the `HttpClient` instead; they’re the opposite and should _not_ be short-lived.

Comment: yes i recon injecting the httpclient would be better this is the first version tough, @JesúsLópez it is injected in the constructor you can see in my code

Comment: @sellotape oke I have created the backgroundservice with the ihostedservice, however i don't fully understand how to implement the dbcontext to create and dispose each iteration?